# Share sshuttle connection over Ubuntu hotspot

Tags: vpn

I am totally noob on the Ubuntu network, I want to know if there is any way to share my `sshuttle` connection with the Ubuntu hotspot. I test the following command in the terminal but it isn't work.
`sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlp0s20f3 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: From what I read, `sshuttle` uses only `ssh`. Can you reach the server with `ssh`?

Comment: yes, I can connect to the server with `sshuttle`, I want to use Ubuntu hotspot to share `sshuttle` connection